# How to calculate the load of the following stairs design

Tags: wood, stairs, load

I just built a stairs made of 2x12 as treads and 2x8 as riser in a very hard red wood.
the riser is glued and screwed with 1/4"x 4" structural screws (4 per steps) into the 1.5" side of the 2x12. the stairs are supported by a L bar 2"x3"x3/16" bolt on both extremities of every steps and on each side of the wall. (I hope is clear...lol)
I've been walking on those stairs for one and half year and I weigh 272lb. but I am required a calculation for a permitting.
where can I find that. Also, I have a revit file of the stairs and some DWG details if that can help.

[image]
[image]

Hi everyone, thank you for you answers... so fast...lol

The width of the treads are 47".
So, I don't need any stamp. I just have to provide design and calcs.
I did the designs (don't know how to upload them here) but I don't know how to do the calculations. If I have at least a calculations template, I should be able to find my way.[image]

Comment: A couple of pictures would help. Interior or exterior? Size and spacing of stringers? Length (span)? Is there a wall on each side of the stairs? What kind of room do they start and stop at?

Comment: Does the AHJ (i.e. the folks who want the permit) require such designs be stamped by a licensed engineer or architect?  Many do so you will want to check with them for exactly what they require.

Comment: How wide are the treads?

Comment: You should not rely on strangers to do the work for you.  Go find an engineer for your own safety.